# How to set timestamp with zone in XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, utc, timestamp-with-timezone, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have DateTime in this format `'2020-11-08T13:05:46.000-07:00'` and trying to set the same to `XMLGregorianCalendar`. it gets automatically converted to `2020-11-08T20:05:46.000+0000`.

Anyway to save it as UTC?

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( "2020-11-08T13:05:46.000-07:00" )
.toInstant()
```

## *java.time*

`XMLGregorianCalendar` is a legacy class, supplanted years ago by `ZonedDateTime`.

Your input has no time zone, only an offset-from-UTC. So parse that string as an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2020-11-08T13:05:46.000-07:00" ) ;
```

Easiest way to adjust to UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) is to extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        String givenDateTimeString = "2020-11-08T13:05:46.000-07:00";
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
                .newXMLGregorianCalendar(givenDateTimeString);
        System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendar);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-11-08T13:05:46.000-07:00
```

However, I suggest you switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

**Using the modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String givenDateTimeString = "2020-11-08T13:05:46.000-07:00";
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(givenDateTimeString);
        // Default format i.e. OffsetDateTime#toString
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Custom format
        System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH)));

        // Convert it to date-time at UTC
        OffsetDateTime odtUTC = odt.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtUTC);
        System.out.println(odtUTC.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-11-08T13:05:46-07:00
2020-11-08T13:05:46.000-07:00
2020-11-08T20:05:46Z
2020-11-08T20:05:46.000Z
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.